# How to make Cypress test fail if it makes a request that does not have an intercept associated with it?

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

How to make Cypress test fail if it makes a request that does not have an intercept associated with it?

Let's say cypress navigates to a page and makes 10 requests. How can I make cypress automatically fail if any of those requests are not intercepted. I don't want any requests made from cypress to NOT be mocked.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check the `cy.intercept()` coverage of app requests, add a middleware intercept.

Generally you want the middleware to catch a broad range of URL's, for example all the API calls would be caught with

```js
cy.intercept('**/api/**/*')
```

Middleware intercepts always see the captured calls first, and then pass them on to remaining intercepts.

---

This example checks the GET calls during loading of `https://cypress.io/`.

```js
cy.intercept('https://www.cypress.io/_astro/**/*') // the intercept in my test
                                                   // want to check for unhandled calls

// Middleware intercept - catches all calls
const calls = []
cy.intercept('https://www.cypress.io/**/*', { middleware: true }, (req) => {
  calls.push(req.url)
}).as('all')

cy.visit('https://cypress.io/')    // now visit the site

cy.then(() => {

  // Use routes state info to compare handled calls vs all calls
  const handledUrls = Object.values(cy.state('routes'))
    .filter(route => route.alias !== 'all')
    .map(route => Object.values(route.requests)
      .map(interceptedRequest => interceptedRequest.request.url)
    })
    .flat()

  // Find the unhandled calls
  const unhandled = calls.filter(call => !handledUrls.includes(call))
  console.log('Unhandled calls: ', unhandled)

})
```

Logs two unhandled calls:

```js
[
  'https://www.cypress.io/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js', 
  'https://www.cypress.io/videos/home_page.webm'
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Cypress emits an event that can be used to grab all requests.

```js
const requests = []
Cypress.on('request:event', (eventName, data) => {
  if (eventName === 'incoming:request') {
    requests.push(data)
  }
})
```

Use a custom command to calculate the unhandled URL's.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('unhandledRequests', () => {
  const { _ } = Cypress
  const handledRequestIds = _.map(cy.state('routes'), 'requests')
    .map(request => _.map(request, 'browserRequestId')).flat() 
  return requests.reduce((acc,r) => 
    !handledRequestIds.includes(r.requestId) ? acc.concat(r.url) : acc
  , [])
})
```

---

#### Example test

```js
const requests = []
Cypress.on('request:event', (eventName, data) => {
  if (eventName === 'incoming:request') {
    requests.push(data)
  }
})

Cypress.Commands.add('unhandledRequests', () => {
  const { _ } = Cypress
  const handledRequestIds = _.map(cy.state('routes'), 'requests')
    .map(request => _.map(request, 'browserRequestId')).flat() 
  return requests.reduce((acc,r) => 
    !handledRequestIds.includes(r.requestId) ? acc.concat(r.url) : acc
  , [])
})

cy.intercept('**/api/1', {})    // Only intercepts the first call

cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('domain/api/1')
  win.fetch('domain/api/2')   // will not be intercepted   
})

cy.wrap(requests).should('have.length', 2)    // ensure both requests seen

cy.unhandledRequests()
  .should('have.length', 1)
  .and(unhandled => {
    assert(unhandled[0].match('domain/api/2'), 'Found unmatched "domain/api/2"')
  })
```

---

#### Globally across all specs

Put this part in `cypress/support/e2e.js` to act globally on all specs.

```js
let requests = []
Cypress.on('request:event', (eventName, data) => {
  if (eventName === 'incoming:request') {
    requests.push(data)
  }
})

Cypress.Commands.add('unhandledRequests', () => {
  const { _ } = Cypress
  const handledRequestIds = _.map(cy.state('routes'), 'requests')
    .map(request => _.map(request, 'browserRequestId')).flat() 
  return requests.reduce((acc,r) => 
    !handledRequestIds.includes(r.requestId) ? acc.concat(r.url) : acc
  , [])
})

Cypress.Commands.add('resetRequests', () => {
  requests = []
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at how the cypress local runner is displaying this information and I've followed the same approach.
Add the below method in your test file.
The method can be put either in an individual test file or in your support.ts file if you want to apply it to all tests. I've left console.logs intentionally so you can inspect the object structure and what's happening in the browser console.

```
afterEach(() => {
    console.log((Cypress as any).ProxyLogging.proxyRequests);
    const callsNotMocked = (Cypress as any).ProxyLogging.proxyRequests
        .filter((req: any) => !req.flags?.stubbed)
        .map((req: any) => req.preRequest?.method + ' ' + req.preRequest?.url);

    if (callsNotMocked > 0) {
        console.log(callsNotMocked);
        cy.log('BEGIN REQUESTS NOT MOCKED');
        for (let i = 0; i < callsNotMocked.length; i++) {
            cy.log(`_${callsNotMocked[i]}_`);
        }
        cy.log('END REQUESTS NOT MOCKED');
    }

    const callsNotMockedStr = callsNotMocked.join(' \n');
    throw Error(`The following requests are not mocked: ${callsNotMockedStr }`);
});
```

Refs:

- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/driver/src/cypress/proxy-logging.ts
- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/driver/src/cy/net-stubbing/events/before-request.ts